# install cURL in php 7 (ubuntu14.04)

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl

I have `php7` installed on `ubuntu 14.04`

I have problems with `curl`
I tried to run `composer install` and it gives me error
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - `stripe/stripe-php v2.3.0 requires ext-curl *`-> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

I also tried `sudo apt-get install php-curl`. This gives me output:

E: Unable to locate package php-curl

Help

Comment: PHP 7 is very new. Ubuntu 14.04 is not. PHP 7 does not appear in its [standard package repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all)… so any advice on how to install the cURL extension for it would depend on what method you used to install it in the first place.

Comment: actually 
sudo apt-get install php-curl 

This is very common solution found on google.
But doesn't work on my system. 
It gives me:

 unable to locate package php-curl

Comment: That is because it, like PHP 7 itself, is not a native part of Ubuntu 14.04. Which brings us back to my previous comment, "it would depend on what method you used to install it in the first place" … so **how did you install PHP 7?**

Comment: by adding ppa

ppa:ondrej/php-7.0

Answer (score 18):

Try using:

```
 sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl
```

Comment: That [doesn't seem likely to work](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=php7.0-curl&searchon=names)

Comment: Tried it on my system:

`swapnil@HOME:~$ sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl`

`Reading package lists... Done`

`Building dependency tree       `

`Reading state information... Done`

`php7.0-curl is already the newest version.`

`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 274 not upgraded.`

Comment: Is your system ubuntu 14.04? It doesn't work for me: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAN-9tnP0zdCRIyQw9NuoftWHZgUugQ3Yfc

Comment: DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu

DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04

DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty

DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"

Comment: Sorry for the text formatting ..can't seem to get it right :)

Comment: This command ended up with message:

E: Unable to locate package php7.0-curl
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-curl'

Comment: I get the same output as @Quentin

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Install cURL:

`sudo apt-get install php-curl` OR `sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl`

2. Enable cURL extension in `php.ini` file. `;extension=php_curl.dll` Uncomment this.

All done, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Installing `php 7 curl` in `kali linux`
If you installed your `php7` manually,
Open your terminal and simply type 
`sudo apt-get install php-curl` without quotes and you are done.

I experienced the same problem when installing `stripe payment` system but that solved my problem.